# Which MySQL JOIN is suitable for this?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

1. Users (id, email, password)
2. Feed_items (id, title, feed_id)
3. Subscriptions (id, user_id, feed_id)

What I'm trying to do is get all of the feed items that a user is subscribed to by mapping `id` in Users and `feed_id` in Feed_items to `user_id` and `feed_id` in Subscriptions.

Because there are three tables, I'm thrown and unsure which join(s) to use here.

Answer (score 2):

You can so inner join as

```
select 
u.id,
u.email,
f.title
from Subscriptions s 
inner join Users u on u.id = s.user_id
inner join Feed_items f on f.feed_id = s.feed_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm currently implementing this - would it return with the list of feed items (entire rows) that the user is subscribed to?

Comment: yes I would suggest to use them in the select as `f.id as fid,f. feed_id`

Comment: I have now have this string `$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT 'u.id', 'u.email', 'f.title' FROM sh_subscriptions s INNER JOIN sh_users u on 'u.id' = 's.user_id' INNER JOIN shopaholic f on 'f.feed_id' = 's.feed_id' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 72 OFFSET" . $offset);` but I'm getting the error `mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given`

Comment: u cant use single quote in the field or table name, wither use backtics or dont use them .`SELECT u.id,
u.email, 
f.title
FROM sh_subscriptions s 
INNER JOIN sh_users u on u.id = s.user_id
INNER JOIN shopaholic f on f.feed_id = s.feed_id
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 72 OFFSET`

Comment: try this `$query = mysqli_query("SELECT u.id,
u.email, 
f.title
FROM sh_subscriptions s 
INNER JOIN sh_users u on u.id = s.user_id
INNER JOIN shopaholic f on f.feed_id = s.feed_id
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 72");`

Answer (score 0):

You need to join both tables,

```
select * from a a1, a a2, a a3 where a1.a = a2.a and a2.a = a3.a
```

The important thing is to keep the logic you intend:

```
select * from Users a,Feed_items b, Subscriptions C 
where a.id = c.user_id and b.id = c. feed_id
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `JOIN`'s rather then using 'the old way'.

Comment: People have the tendency to assume that if theyr wrote a join in specific order - the DBMS engine will perform the joins by that order... I like this syntax more because it is clear to the reader they're not in charge of it .. I use the "join" syntax only when it is necessary because of it .. but it is a matter of taste...  they're equivalent

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM subscriptions s
INNER JOIN feed_items f ON s.feed_id = f.id
WHERE s.user_id = 'yourUserId'
```

Or, if you want user information as well:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
INNER JOIN subscriptions s ON u.id = s.user_id
INNER JOIN feed_items f ON s.feed_id = f.id
WHERE u.id = 'yourUserId'
```